# Скатывается текст в div'е (CSS, Bootstrap)

Tags: css, bootstrap

Добрый вечер!

Учусь верстать адаптивные сайты по макетам, столкнулся с такой проблемой: текст расположенный в div скатывается под него, как задать ему четкую позицию, но что-бы он не скатывался? 
Заранее благодарен за любую помощь.
Прикрепляю скриншоты с разметкой и самой страницей в разных размерах:

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Snow</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="favicon" href="favicon.ico"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=450, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="headerblock">
        <div class=".col-xs-12 .col-md-12 .col-sm-12">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" class="adaptive_logo"></a>
            <a class="menu" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="main-photo">
        <img src="img/main.png" class="main" width="960" height="640">
    </div>


    <div id="container">
        <p class="leftside">I create <i><b>everything</b></i> digital,<br> printable & minimal</p>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:700i');

.logo {
  margin-left: -1115px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 34px;
}

.fa-bars {
    right: 15%;
    margin-top: 34px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
}

.fa-bars:hover {
    color: #666;
    transition: 1s;
}

a.menu{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

a.menu:hover{
    color: #333;
    transition: 1s;
}

a.menu:hover::before{
    color: #000;
    transition: 1s;
}


.adaptive_logo {
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3.6%;
    left: 15%;
}

.main {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 35px;
}

#headerblock {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 5.000em;
    width: 100%;
}

#container{
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    height: 40.063em;
    width: 100%;
}

p.leftside {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    font-size: 1.875em;
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: -10%;
    left: 15%;
    display: inline;
    color: #020202;
    word-wrap: normal;
}

p.rightside {
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.938em;
    color: #696969;
    display: inline;
    word-wrap: normal;

}
```

[image: Текст]

[image: Текст]

Comment: Желательно приложить код, HTML и CSS.

Comment: Прикрепил код..

Comment: <div class=".col-xs-12 .col-md-12 .col-sm-12"> - тут не должно быть точки перед названиями классов

Comment: Пофиксил, спасибо :) - Но на текст увы не повлияло :D

Comment: Посмотрите в примерах Boostrap как это все делается. HTML код можно и нужно сократить. Используйте возможности фреймворка, если уж работаете с ним, там все это есть.

Answer (score 0):

Исправил добавив

```
max-width: 250px;
```

Comment: это для какого элемента такой стиль понадобился? Выглядит скорее как костыль на ровном месте, чем "решение".

Comment: @MedvedevDev - Ну, я бы хотел посмотреть на ваше решение. Я еще плохо разбираюсь во всём этом :)

Comment: Зачем вообще позиционировать текст абсолютно? На вскидку проблема в том, что position: absolute; bottom:-10%; - этого я вообще не понял.

Comment: Ну, я не откажусь от совета :)

Comment: А совет таков ... не используй position: absolute; без особой нужды))) В em'ах высоту указывать это тоже странная метода, очень редко встречаются проекты где это реально требуется, обычно это лендинги с контентом "на один экран". Ты же получаешь то, что получаешь, чем больше твоя страница, тем выше контейнер, тем ниже будет опускаться твой текст, то что ты задал тексту макс ширину - это не решило проблему. Если учишься только адаптиву, то начни с того, что бы задавать в % и em только ширину элементов или размер шрифта, забудь про абсолютное позиционирование на пока так же.

Comment: Я полагаю нужно каждый элемент в отдельный div и ему уже задавать позицию, или как?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56738/discussion-between-medvedevdev-and-user234223).

Comment: Да у тебя структура то простая, при чем тут дивы?) Просто контейнеру не задавай высоту без надобности никогда, нужен отступ текста от границ - делай это паддингами, а не высотой блока и абсолютным позиционированием, это же основы и не важно в адаптивной или нет верстке.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/cmTGL в данный момент страница и так имеет вот такой вид

Comment: @MedvedevDev Кажется что-то начало получатся, правда теперь отступ большой при маленьком разрешении:)

HTML:

https://gist.github.com/Tvarinsky/1dde4d9d6f6db254a8308e2b745e2201

Comment: CSS: https://gist.github.com/Tvarinsky/e1e4e411ef8b2b4b3f26e0cbf8a04afb

Comment: Залей целиком куда-нибудь свою страницу (разметку, стили, скрипты), а тот же гит (ну или просто файлопомойку), дай ссылку, так будет проще, просто без картинок и прочего по кускам воссоздавать страницы, не имея тех же самых картинок, мне честно говоря лениво.

Comment: http://rgho.st/7yWnj5VKw

Comment: @MedvedevDev - сойдет на rghost?